# How to train and evaluate Keras Sequential Neural Network through tf.Dataset Pipeline

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to put together a keras Sequential model and train/evaluate it on a large dataset by using the Dataset api. I'm seeing bits and pieces of how to do this, but nowhere that fits it all together. 
My data source is a large csv file.
I see samples of how to parse out the csv file through the TextLineDataset's iterator (plus a decode_csv utility function), but I don't see how to fit this into the basic Keras model creation...training pattern, like:

```
    #create model
    model = models.Sequential()
    #add layers
    model.add(layers.Dense(..., activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(...,acticvation='relu'))
    ...
    model.add(layers.Dense(...,activation='tanh')
    #compile model
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',...)
    #train
    model.fit(???)
    #evaluate
    model.evaluate(???)
```

1. Is this pattern possible with the tf.data.Dataset way of doing things, and if not, what is the preferred pattern?
2. How do I train a keras Sequential with data fed through the Dataset API pipeline's iterators?

Comment: Maybe you have solved it already, but if not, turning your keras model to TF estimators (using `tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator()` ), could be a solution.